# What are my options for pulling a subset of records from a large database table based on information in a local file?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

I am attempting to pull a subset (a few thousand) records from a large Oracle database table, where the IDs of those records are specified in (and already extracted from) a local file.

Since the data set with the IDs is local, there is no way to do this through a join, and I do not have permissions to create any temporary tables in the database. The number of records I need (again, a few thousand, and increasing over time) seems too large to pass into the query through an IN clause.

Are there any suggestions on a method I could use to do this without pulling in the entire table?

Although the question is phrased more generically, if the specifics matter, I am using the cx-Oracle library in Python to query the database, and mostly working with Pandas DataFrames to work with the data afterwards.

Comment: Why can't you just chunk the list of ID's into lists of 500 and run your IN query on those lists, concatenate the results?

Comment: @roganjosh That is the one option I thought of, and probably the way I would go if I can't come up with anything else. I guess I was hoping there was something a little cleaner. But maybe not!

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to transfer the data to the database, anything will be a kludgy solution.  But you can pass more than 1000 elements via a nested table, and still reference those rows within an SQL statement using the TABLE() operator, eg

```
SQL>     set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    s sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4);
  3
  4  begin
  5    for i in
  6      ( select * from table(s) )
  7    loop
  8      dbms_output.put_line(i.column_value);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
1
2
3
4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    s sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4);
  3    c int;
  4  begin
  5    for i in 1 .. dbms_random.value(6000,8000) loop
  6      s.extend;
  7      s(s.count) := i;
  8    end loop;
  9
 10    select count(*) into c from table(s);
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Still fine with '||c||' elements');
 12  end;
 13  /
Still fine with 7429 elements

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```